# How to import dojo javascript file into worklight application?

Tags: javascript, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

When creating a new project, I have selected to include the dojo toolkit. I can import dojo.js using `src="dojo/dojo.js"`. However when I try importing some other modules such as dijit.js using

```
require(["dijit/dijit"], function(){})
```

...I always get an error in the web console (ie the resource is not found). The problem is not applied when I import dojo modules. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made simple mistake of syntax:-
To require js file instead of `require[("dojo/parser")]`
you have use `require(["dojo/parser"],function(parser){})`

Comment: Thanks. Actually I used the same syntax as you suggested and it loads dojo modules without problems (question updated). The problem is when I try to load dijit js file. Any suggestion?

Comment: There is some problem in base your base path. I have use `require(["dijit/dijit"])` and its working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, you have configured Dojo correctly, kindly find the Dojo configuration which I have been using in my Hybrid App.

```
<script>
    var dojoConfig = {
    baseUrl: "js",
    packages: [
        { name: "dojo", location: "dojo/dojo"},
        { name: "dijit", location: "dojo/dijit"},
        { name: "dojox", location: "dojo/dojox"}
    ],
        isDebug: false,
        async: true,
        parseOnLoad: true,
        deps:['app/main']
    }
</script>
```

If you still not able to resolve it, try to make a sample use case or jsfiddle, would look into it further.